# Selenium Error: "unrecognized proxy type: MANUAL"

Tags: python, exception, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error

I'm trying to learn how to run a selenium webdriver with a proxy server, but directly following the documentation with the provided code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
"httpProxy": PROXY,
"ftpProxy": PROXY,
"sslProxy": PROXY,
"proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

yields the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Invalid proxyType value: MANUAL

Is the documentation outdated or is there something else I'm not taking into account here?

The documentation in question can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the value from `MANUAL` to `manual` you can get rid of below exception

```
Message: Invalid proxyType value: MANUAL
```

And if you get below exception then remove this line `"ftpProxy": PROXY,`.

```
Message: SessionNotCreatedError: InvalidArgumentError: Since Firefox 90 'ftpProxy' is no longer supported
```

Refer code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
"httpProxy": PROXY,
"sslProxy": PROXY,
"proxyType": "manual",
}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```